# Java File.lastModified returned value changes if timezone changes?

Tags: java, android, file

Is the function lastModified from class File returning allways the same value even if the current device time is updated or even if the user changes the device timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.lastModified` corresponds to the last time the file that `File` points to was updated, and it's expressed in UTC milliseconds since the Epoch (1-1-1970). So, no, it does not change unless you modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `File.lastmodified` is a static value (that can be updated, if you 'modify the file', obviously)

However, it is technically possible for 'root' on a linux system to modify the value https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file (yes, I know... not 'Android', but Android runs the linux kernel and can probably do the same thing. if the person has rooted their phone.)

So it is 'technically' possible to change that value, but 'realistically' it won't change unless the file is changed/modified/etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking if the returned value depends from the current timezone and, following the previous answer, is stored in UTC, that don't depends from the user timezone.

Comment: Yeah, but I just wanted to point out that your title's 'question' about being immutable is technically 'no'. It 'can' be changed(even without 'modifying the file', but only by root). (I wasn't sure which part of the question 'immutable' or 'timezone' was the most important to you)

Comment: Thanks. Just changed the question title :)